# Detect whether logical volumes inside VMware are on the same physical disc

Tags: vmware

I have access to Windows Server 2008 virtual machine which runs as a guest inside VMware. Is there any way how to find out whether logical volumes of this server are on the same physical disc?

Answer (score 0):

Install a disk benchmark program. Run it only on one volume and then only on second volume. After that run it at the same time on both volumes. If the disk throughput is significantly lower per volume when you run test simultaneously on both volumes then they're probably on the same physical disk.
However, this test can be unreliable if storage behind this is RAID array, external storage system, etc.